# Does C# code contained in Javascript still need to be compiled?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

We have a web application built with C# and ASP.NET.  I have to reference a few .NET session variables in my JavaScript code, so I use the following line to do so:

```
var layoutID = '<%=Server.UrlEncode(string.Format("{0}", Session["layout_id"]))%>';
```

This works just fine.  The web application is built and published to our web server.  If I want to make a change, a .NET change would require me to compile the changes and publish it to the web server again.  If it's a JavaScript change, I can simply edit the js in the .ASPX page and the fix is immediately picked up...no compiling needed.

My question - what if I make a change to this inline C# code contained in JavaScript?  Say, for example, I meant to access Session["layoutid"] without the underscore.  Could I just edit the .ASPX page on the web server, or will this require compiling just as if it were in a .CS file?  I'm guessing since it's C#, I will still need to compile for the change to be picked up.  And yes I could just try it and see for myself, but I was hoping someone could give a little insight into what goes on behind the scenes with this inline c# code.  And while we're on the topic, is the technique I'm using to access .NET sessions variables in JavaScript the most efficient way to do it?
Bonus question - what is this technique called?  I tried searching for an answer but I wasn't sure what to search for other than "in-line c# code JavaScript".

Thanks!

Comment: First of all "eval is evil" you should never store code in strings. Second, if you want to make minor changes in any development no matter what language you should not recompile each time you could store the parameters in a database table, config file or something like that.

Comment: I have made similar changes in code in the past year and did not need to compile if that helps.... But i agree it is not a good practice.

Comment: Couldn't this be answered much more quickly by just trying it?

Comment: Yes it could, but as I stated in my question I was curious about what went on behind the scenes with this type of code and if it was best practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, changes to ASPX/CSHTML files don't require re-compilation.

Note: whether it is good idea to jump on production server and change random code bypassing source control/testing is question to discuss and answer by your team.

Comment: Thanks Alexei.  This is a special circumstance, but you're right, normally I would never jump out to production and make a change like this.